# C++ pass vector and variable by reference without knowing their data type

Tags: c++

I want to create a function in which I pass a vector and a variable by reference. The tricky part is that I do not know the data type of the parameters.

```
void addElement(std::vector<auto> &base, auto &element, int index) // index stands for index in vector
{
    ...
}
```

I want to add `element` to `base`. However, I want `base` to be able to be both data types `vector<int>` and `vector<vector<int>>` and consequently I want `element` to be both data types `int` and `vector<int>`. I get error messages that `auto` keyword does not fit in this context. Is there any way to do something similar to this without overwriting the function?

Comment: You may want to look at templates

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with templates:

```cpp
template<class T>
void addElement(vector<T> &vec, T &element, int index){
   //push-back is for easy example
   vec.push_back(element);
}
```

The only thing you should call it like this, because element is passed by reference:

```cpp
   vector<int> myVec;
   int add = 42;
   addElement(myVec, add, 0);
```

For using this code without introducing new variable, consider adding `const` to the element declaration.
`void addElement(vector<T> &vec, const T &element, int index)`

Comment: Or make it `const T& element`. That way the `add` variable isn't needed. Or: `T&& element` and `vec.emplace_back(std::forward<T>(element));`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using templates in C++. The idea is to pass data type as a parameter.
You can use reference as [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/templates-cpp/), [Cplusplus Referance](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/) of template in C++. And add an element in a desire position of a vector [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-insert-function-in-c-stl/).

**Reference Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<class T> void addElement(vector<T>& vec, const T& element, int index)
{
    // Insert at position [index]
    // Example: Current vector: 1, 2, 4, 5
    // Insert at 2 position with the value 3 [0 based index]
    // Now current vector will be: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    vec.insert(vec.begin() + index, element);
}



int main ()
{
    vector<int> vec{1, 2, 4, 5};
    int element = 3, index = 2;
    addElement(vec, element, 2);
    for(auto el : vec)
    {
        cout << el << endl;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1 2 3 4 5
```